# Ignore messages that are received after Stop() in Akka.net

Tags: c#, akka.net

I have a `ProcessOrdersActor` that looks something like below. It receives a `ProcessABatchOfOrders` command which it then delegates to it's children (`OrderHandler`), which runs with a `RoundRobinPool`. The children answers with either `OrderFailedToProcess` or 
`FinishedWithOrder`. If `ProcessOrdersActor` receives a single one `OrderFailedToProcess` the entire batch should be considered contaminated and everything will be aborted.

This works fine, except when I stop the `OrderHandler` it will still continue to process the current message (which of course is by design). Because of that it will send a `FinishedWithOrder` to it's parent. The problem is that the parent then already started working with another batch of orders, and will therefore be mixing orders.

I want to flush the remaining `FinishedWithOrder` before I start to process a new `ProcessABatchOfOrders`. Is this possible?

I had an idea that it could be solved with a custom `Mailbox` that prioritizes `FinishedWithOrder` and then makes sure that they are received as dead letters in `Ready`-state. This however creates a second question, how do I use a custom `Mailbox` in a unit test based on `TestKit`?

```
    public class ProcessOrdersActor: ReceiveActor, IWithUnboundedStash
    {
        private IActorRef orderHandlers;

        public ProcessOrdersActor()
        {
             this.orderHandlers = Context
                .ActorOf(Props.Create(() => new OrderHandler())
                .WithRouter(new RoundRobinPool(10))), "OrderHandler");
            Ready();
        }

        private void BecomeReady()
        {
            UnbecomeStacked();
            Stash.UnstashAll();
        }

        private void Ready()
        {
            Receive<ProcessABatchOfOrders>(cmd=>
            {
                foreach (var order in cmd.Orders)
                {
                    // Delegate processing to children in router
                    orderHandler.Tell(new ProcessOrder(order), 
                }
                BecomeStacked(() => WaitingForProcesses());
            });
        }

        private void WaitingForProcesses()
        {

            Receive<OrderFailedToProcess>(msg =>
            {
                // One order failed. Then this entire batch should abort.

                // It can also be done with Supervision, but here I stop the children with Stop().
                this.orderHandlers.Stop();
                // Here I want to make sure that no message from orderHandlers will return here.
                BecomeReady();
            });

            Receive<FinishedWithOrder>(msg =>
            {
                // Here I will receive a from previous FinishedWithOrder batch, which I do not want.

                // Do stuff. And when all orders are processed I will swap state again...
                if(everythingIsDone)
                    BecomeReady();            
            });

            ReceiveAny(o => Stash.Stash());
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, stash messages in the router actor, when worker actor become idle unstash message in worker actor, if you recieved `OrderFailedToProcess` message purge the stash from router actor.

This repo has the similar approach only difference it uses Kafka as a message storage.
[AkkaKafka](https://github.com/eahmet/AkkaKafka)